# Is there a way to know when CANCEL is pressed in the Apple Pay view

Tags: ios, applepay

Is there a way to know when CANCEL is pressed in the Apple Pay view? I tried to look for a delegate, but didn't find one.

Answer (score 7):

If you have the PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate methods setup, you can catch the cancel in this method:

```
    - (void)paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
```

I set a boolean (applePaymentDidSucceed) to FALSE before I call Apple Pay, then set it to true if the "PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus" in this method is true:

```
    - (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                   didAuthorizePayment...
```

if ( ! applePaymentDidSucceed), the user cancelled.

Comment: I would expect PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus to contain a canceled field..

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is!

You can use `session.oncancel` event

More info here:
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession
-  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/applepaysession/1778029-oncancel

Comment: this one is only for web

Answer (score -1):

You will get an error. There are several error codes defined, one is for the user cancelling the payment, another for a user having paid purchases disabled in their settings, and all kinds of other errors (for example, you can't make purchases without internet access).

So no particular case for cancellation, just an error.

Comment: and where do i handle the error? or know which error it is?

Comment: You won't get an error for cancellation, because `didAuthorizePayment` won't be called. The other answer here about using a boolean to track state is a better approach.